# Centering images that have been absolutely positioned

Tags: css, html, gallery, center

So I'm using [this pure CSS sliding gallery](http://codepen.io/rilwis/pen/InhHE) without the transition effects, and it's working pretty great so far.

However, not all my images are the same size! This wouldn't be a problem, except all the full-view images seem to be aligned to the left, and it would look much nicer if they were centered.

I've tried settingthe margins to auto, and playing around with putting it all in another centered container, but it doesn't seem to be working. I think it has something to do with the fact that the full-view images have their position set to absolute.

Does anyone have any suggestions?
EDIT: Here's what I'm using right now and here it is in [Jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CPsmg/)

HTML:

```
    <div class="imagescontainer">    
<div id="images"><br />
<a href="images/large_lioxposter1.png" target="_blank"><img src="http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/6471/6eor.png" alt="Liox Poster 1" name="image1" id="image1"  /></a>
<img id="image2" src="http://img89.imageshack.us/img89/8955/ha1e.png" />
<img id="image3" src="http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/6363/1k48.png" />
<img id="image4" src="http://img577.imageshack.us/img577/5867/a26z.png" /></div></div>
<center>
<div id="slider">
<a href="#image1"><img src="images/mini_lioxposter1.png" alt="LIOX Poster"/></a>
<a href="#image2"><img src="images/mini_lioxposter2.png" alt="LIOX dimensions" /></a>
<a href="#image3"><img src="images/mini_lioxposter3.png" alt="Technical drawings" /></a>
<a href="#image4"><img src="images/mini_lioxposter4.png" alt="Technical drawings" /></a></div></center>

 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.imagescontainer
{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
border-style:dotted;
text-align:center;
}
#images {
height: 270px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
margin: 5px auto;
}

#images img {

height: 250px;
padding-top:10px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: -600px;
z-index: 1;
opacity: 0;
}

#images img:target {
left: 0;
z-index: 9;
opacity: 1;
}

#images img:first-child {

opacity: 1;
}

#images:hover

{
opacity:0.5;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple use this simple trick, that will center it vertically as well as horizontally:

```
#images img {
  top:50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 440px;
  margin-top: -125px; /* Half the height */
  margin-left: -220px; /* Half the width */
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/CPsmg/1/

Also see reference: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
img {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Hey there. I gave that a shot and it still doesn't seem to be centering. I've added what I'm using, so you can see :)

Comment: Hmm, it still doesn't seem to be working. The image does end up in the middle, but everything else slides behind it. Thankyou for helping though :)